# In C#, how do I get required number of decimal point values without rounding?

Tags: c#, floating-point, rounding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# Double - ToString() formatting with two decimal places but no rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453951/c-double-tostring-formatting-with-two-decimal-places-but-no-rounding)

I'm using float numbers and I want to get the number of decimal points without any rounding-off being performed.

For Eg. float x = 12.6789
If I want upto 2 decimal points, then I should get (x = 12.67) and NOT (x = 12.68) which happens when rounding takes place.

Plz suggest which is the best way to do this.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? Please post your code and explain where you are having problems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to use [**Math.Truncate()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d101hyf.aspx) for this:

```
decimal x = 12.6789m;
x = Math.Truncate(x * 100) / 100; //This will output 12.67
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by casting:

```
float x = 12.6789;
float result = ((int)(x * 100.0)) / 100.0;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a framework call for this, but you could always write one like:

```
//Scale up, floor, then round down.
//ie: 1.557 
//    scaled up: 155.7
//    floord:  155
//    scaled down: 1.55
public float MyTruncate(float f, int precision){
   float scale = precision * 10;
   return (Math.Floor(f * scale)) / scale;
}
```