# String format - Simple thousands and hundreds

Tags: c#, string

I have the following :

```
value = 15123;
value.ToString("#,0K", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture);
```

The output of this is : `15.199K`

But I want it to output the following : `15.1K`

I sincerely don't understand how to get it. I am trying to accomplish the same number format that stackoverflow has, regarding feedback scoring.

US Example :

```
9823 = 9,823
10198 = 10,1K
```

Spain Example :

```
9823 = 9.823
10198 = 10.1K
```

Thanks

Comment: Also, this might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744264/c-sharp-how-to-format-a-double-to-one-decimal-place-without-rounding

Comment: One K is 1024, not 1000.  Just divide to get what you want instead of hoping that the thousands separator is the right glyph.  It won't.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks Hans. I am trying to do a similar display has SO has.

Comment: "has SO has" is a communication problem as well.  Just speak normally to SO users and your users and it will all make sense to everybody.

Comment: Sorry you are right, I mean Stack Overflow. Feedback numbering format.

Comment: SO uses auto-scaling that you won't get from any format-string. Write some code.

Answer (score 1):

Try with a `.`.

```
value.ToString("#,.0K", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture);
```

Check out the <kbd>[.NetFiddle](http://dotnetfiddle.net/MbNONH)</kbd>:

Output: `15.1K`.

UPDATE: I created another <kbd>[.NetFiddle](http://dotnetfiddle.net/tyGUE9)</kbd> with `CurrentCulture` (as suggested by @Lukazoid ). Please try it from Spain and let us know if it works.

The code would be

```
value.ToString("#,.0K", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Comment: Doing that I don't get it respecting the UI culture, I get : 15,1K , however the expected result should be : 15.1K

Comment: This is the correct answer and returns exactly `15.1K`.

Comment: It returs 15.1K because you are in US. I want it to be dependent on UI Culture.

Comment: Added a .netFiddle example: What UI Culture are you in @user2779312 ?

Comment: I am on Spain, but it should be culture dependent, not hardcoded or US only.

Comment: So, if you write it with a `.`, it becomes a `,` in a culture where this is the expected value, clearly changing depending on culture, and you're saying it's not culture dependent. I think you want it to be culture independent?

Comment: I think `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` is what should be used when formatting values. `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture` is for language resources. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/329033/what-is-the-difference-between-currentculture-and-currentuiculture-properties-of)

Comment: Thanks @Lukazoid I created another .NetFiddle, but someone from Outside US should test it. I guess I can change the Culture on my PC too...

Answer (score 0):

So I made some code, and it works as I expect. If anyone have any ideas how to improve it, it's a pleasure to change it.

```
public static string GetAbbreviatedScore(int value)
{
    string result = "0";

    if (value > 0 && value < 10000)
    {
        result = value.ToString("#,#", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture);
    }
    else if (value >= 10000 && value < 100000)
    {
        if (value.ToString().EndsWith("000"))
        {
            result = value.ToString("#,#K", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture).Remove(1,4);
        }
        else
        {
        result = value.ToString("#,#K", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture).Remove(3,2);
        }
    }
    else if (value > 100000 && value < 1000000)
    {
        result = value.ToString("#,#K", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture).Remove(2,4);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Thank you very much