# How to Convert Decimal to 2 fraction

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

How to Convert Decimal to 2 fraction.  example I want to convert 10.5234 to 10.52 and if the fraction is 0 disappear the fraction and 4.3014 convert to 4.3

Comment: `MyVariable.ToString("N:2")`

Comment: and what if it is integer? 4.0 or 4. or 4? target data type string? decimal point localized?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you round a number to two decimal places in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257005/how-do-you-round-a-number-to-two-decimal-places-in-c)

Comment: Or a duplicate of this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453951/c-sharp-double-tostring-formatting-with-two-decimal-places-but-no-rounding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
String.Format("{0:0.##}", myNumber);
```

You can have a look at the [Custom Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx)
 documentation.

If you use C#6.0 or above, you can use string interpolation like this:

```
$"{myNumber:0.##}"
```

as suggested by [Jeppe Stig Nielsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1336654/jeppe-stig-nielsen)

Comment: Nowadays people use string interpolation instead, so that is `$"{myNumber:0.##}"`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen thanks for info, I edited accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You can do it yourself like this:

```
double toConvert = 10.5234;
double converted = ((int)Math.round(toConvert * 100)) / 100.0;
```

It will round your number to two decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

```
        double NumberToRound1 = 10.5234;
        double NumberToRound2 = 4.3014;
        //You can use Math.Round as follow
        Math.Round(NumberToRound1, 2);

        Math.Round(NumberToRound2, 2);
```

Desired Output:

[image]